# Error loading script: Unable to get property 'version' of undefined or null reference

Tags: python, conda, altair

[**Error loading script: Unable to get property 'version' of undefined or null reference**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXPP8.png)

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This error comes up in Altair when using an unsupported browser, such as Internet Explorer. Please try running the code in an ES6-compliant browser, such as Firefox or Chrome.

For more information, see https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html